# Multiple replaceWith<>() actions

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have two views in the tornadofx Kotlin app.

Within View # 1 input for certain initial values is performed, certain calculations are made and results are added to mutableListOf <>().
Then View # 1 is replacedWith View # 2 upon pressing the button "Next). The results of calculation are demonstrated in View # 2 in the set of

fileldset{
field("") {label(SimpleFloatProperty(result1))}

}

When the first replaceWith View # 2 operation is performed everything is fine. 
But.
In some cases the user has to return to View # 1, change some initial values there, perform the same calculations with the new input and go again to View # 2 to view updated results. I send him to View # 1 with replaceWith command initiated by the button "Back".
He comes back to View # 2 by the button "Next" (= replaceWith View #2).

And here comes the problem. All output (field(""){label (SimpleFloatProperty(result1))}in View # 2 remains the same. They do not change! Despite the fact that the values themselves change OK (debugged that by println of these SimpleFloatProperty).

I tried different workouts - used textfields, for example. It does not help.

I've got a feeling that the fieldset in View is initialized only once - when the View is entered first.

Please, advise how to resolve the described problem.
Thank in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure without any actual code. But yes, TornadoFX `View`s are initialized only once. `Fragments` are initialized every time you call one. If you want to keep it as a `View`, then overriding the `onDock` function sounds like a solution.

Comment: I will say based on your example code, you're not keeping track of your properties, and are just leaving them. Why make a new SimpleFloatProperty in view 2, when you could just have the property belong to a third class that is shared between the views?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did not provide the source code because it's rather big, and I hoped to avoid building a simplified demo app to show. Basically I'm not creating the SImpleFloatProperty in View2. The mutableListOf is determined in the MyApp.kt where class MyApp: App(MainView::class, Styles::class) is listed. So, this mutableListOf is common and is visible from everywhere. I println this SimpleFloatProperty before leaving View1 and it's correct (changed), When coming back to View1 I also println this SimpleFloatProperty - also good. It seems to me right everywhere except the display.

Comment: Hope you figured this out! But a word of advice: This problem sounds like it could be explained easily in less than 10 lines of code per class over three classes. If you're having trouble making a simplified example, maybe your code isn't being written in structured enough way.